# A way to convert hex value to decimal equivailent

Tags: hex, byte, ascii

We have a problem right here we can't seem to get out of.

We have a hexadecimal byte array

Let's say its:

*0x12 0x34*

We now like to output this as ascii char on the display of our device so it should output:

*0x31 0x32 0x33 0x34*

So we'd like to convert between the values of the byte array, and the ascii equivailent of the number in the byte.

Is there anybody who knows how to do this?

Thanks in advance

edit:

ok so we know:
0x85 = 1000 0101
to get 8 we need to grab the left 4 bits.

Answer (score 0):

In C you can use printf,

```
unsigned char array[2] = {0x12, 0x34};
printf("%x%x", array[0], array[1]);
```

prints out "`1234`"

***Edit:***

If you need it to print out `"0x31 0x32 0x33 0x34"` use this,

```
char ascii[] = {"0123456789ABCDEF"};
unsigned char array[] = {0x12, 0x34};
int length = sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]);
int i;
for (i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
    printf("0x%02X 0x%02X ", ascii[(array[i] >> 4) & 0xf], ascii[array[i] & 0xf]);
}
```

prints out "`0x31 0x32 0x33 0x34`"